# hide column and title in telerik grid mvc3 and access them

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

I need to hide the contents of a column and its title in Telerik grid mvc3, so that I can access them later.
I know two functions: `Hiden()` and `visible()`
the code is:

```
foreach (var attr in grid.Attr)
.Columns(columns =>
{
   columns.Bound(attr.key)
     .Width(attr.width)
     .Visible(attr.isVisible);
})
```

or

```
foreach (var attr in grid.Attr)
.Columns(columns =>
{
   columns.Bound(attr.key)
     .Width(attr.width)
     .Hidden(!attr.isVisible);
})
```

But Both of not helping me:
On "`visible()`" it hides my content and title but can not access them.
On "`Hidden()`" I can access the data but it only hides the content and not the title.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you using **.Hidden** then

```
foreach (var attr in grid.Attr)
.Columns(columns =>
{
   columns.Bound(attr.key)
     .Width(attr.width)
     .Hidden(true);
})
```

If you using **.Visible** then

```
foreach (var attr in grid.Attr)
.Columns(columns =>
{
   columns.Bound(attr.key)
     .Width(attr.width)
     .Visible(false);
})
```

So now u can realize, what need to do.

Comment: I do not understand what you say?